# php scrape: echo the third word only

Tags: php, echo, scrape

So I'm experimenting with php scraping possibilites, and I'd like to get a bit more precise about the data that is being echo'd. The below code is achieving this output: DJIA All Time, Record-High Close: June 14, 2017 (21,374.56)

```
<?php

// weather forecast los angeles
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=%5EGSPC');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//span[@class='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
}
?>
```

Is there a possible way anyone knows where I could specify to only output the third word/value that comes up during the scrape. So in the above example, only "Time" would end up getting echo'd. When I'm saying word/value, I guess I'm identifying that as having a " " blank space.

Could this be possible? Sorry about my lack of php skills, quite new to this. If I was able to get this precise hwoever in what is being echo'd, that would raise many possibilities.

Best, -Wilson

Comment: Hello, 2,432.46 this is your output what you want from this?

Comment: I'd like to just be able to choose the third word/value that comes up in the output I'm getting. The third word is "Time". If I chose 2,432.46, which is fine, I believe that would be the ninth value/word. I'm defining this by " " spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explode() php function, which uses to convert a string into an array.

```
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
     $result = trim($entry->textContent); 
     $ret_ = explode(' ', $result);
    echo $ret_[2];

}

Another one

<?php

$text = "DJIA All Time, Record-High Close: June 14, 2017 (21,374.56)";

$text_array = explode(' ', $text);

 print_r($text_array);
 echo $text_array[2];
?>
```

Comment: NVM Fixed it! Just took out the line echo $text_array[2]; // result is a

Comment: Thanks Saroj! You've been super quick and super helpful. Excited to really explore this now.

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Comment: One quick thing, all of the values and words I was able to individualize on the output, except the last value: (21,374.56)   Which just came up blank. Any idea what may be causing that? Hm maybe it's something to do with the parenthesis, and clearly (21, is it's own value because of the space. I wonder if there's any work around in regards to the parenthesis, in case I encounter that in the future

Comment: if you have space in it then it will separate to a another index of the array. If it doesn't have any space then it will give whole string in your last index of the array. You can check it in online(http://www.writephponline.com/) which i give an example.

Comment: Thx. Like the website